# Cannot download updates: Failed Software Update - Refusing invalid certificate from host: swcdn.apple.com

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update

I have a MacBook 2019 and when I am trying to install macOS Ventura I get the following error immediately before the download starts:

> **Installation failed**
> An error occurred while installing the selected updates.

After checking `install.log` (available at About this Mac / System report / Software / Logs) I can see that the download fails with the following error:

```
Failed Software Update - Refusing invalid certificate from host: swcdn.apple.com
```

I have also tried running the `softwareupdate` tool with no luck:

```
➜ softwareupdate -l
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

This generates a similar certificate error for a different URL:

```
Failed Software Update - Refusing invalid certificate from host: swscan.apple.com
```

Opening the specific URLs in the browser shows me they have a valid certificate. As a last effort, I did update the root certificate to be always trusted but this did not help either.

The time is correctly set on my machine.

Have anyone experienced a similar issue? What can be the solution?

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance on a restricted network, or do you have a VPN or some kind of firewall that interferes with your DNS? To rule it out, follow [this Apple Community post.](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-7391)

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one digicert listed under "system" in keychain access then look at removing the one not in the "system roots" category.

Comment: What does this do and how does it solve the problem the OP has? Is it just an idea or a proven way to solve the problem? Are there any side effects? https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer has more details on things we look for in answers.

Comment: Removing a root certificate is a possibly destructive action. I am not comfortable trying this out. As @nohillside mentioned, can you provide more details about why this solves my problem?